# Inserting function in ASP.net is showing error and not executing the Insert query

Tags: c#, asp.net

1. Data comes from "Temp" table.
2. Stored in variables
3. Inserted into "Client" table with the addition of two more variables.
   And there comes an error. The INSERT query is not executing properly.
   Query,

   ```
                     int r;
                     string que = "INSERT INTO client (fname, lname, dob, 
                                  email, gender, uname, upass) VALUES 
                                 ('" + fname + "', 
                                  '" + lname + "', '" + dob + "',
                                  '" + email + "',
                                  '" + gender + "',
                                  '" + TextBox1.Text + "',
                                  '" + TextBox2.Text + "')  ";
                     r = c.savedeldata(que);
   ```

savedeldata Function

```
    public int savedeldata(string qu)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qu, con);
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return i;

    }
```

Comment: Firstly: you have a SQL Injection vulnerability. Second: what error?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'syed'.'

Comment: int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: What 'syed'?  There is no 'syed' for incorrect syntax to be near.

Comment: 'syed' is stored in "string email" the VALUE email which is going to be inserted in client table.

Comment: Start by showing the value of `que` after it is assigned. This is a second reason to not use string concatenation to build sql: it makes getting the right syntax much easier. (The first is of course avoiding SQL Injection). Suggestion: use parameterisation.

Comment: Richard, I have to say that but you were right. It starts by showing the value of que and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the only solution I can find.

if (ds.Tables["0"].Rows.Count == 1)
                        {

```
                        int r;
                        string queryt = "DELETE FROM tbl_client";
                        r = c.savedeldata(queryt);
                        string que = "INSERT INTO tbl_client(fname, lname, dob, email, gender) SELECT * FROM temp WHERE dob = '" + TextBox3.Text + "'";
                        r = c.savedeldata(que);
                        string quer = "UPDATE tbl_client SET uname = '"+ TextBox1.Text +"', upass = '"+ TextBox2.Text +"' WHERE dob = '"+ TextBox3.Text +"'";
                        r = c.savedeldata(quer);

                    }
```

Comment: I found it appropriate and It helps me to solve the problem but after delete and when we apply to update the path address gone to change.